# How can ı make scroll button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the scroll button? So I made 2 buttons. The first button has an up arrow icon and the other a down arrow icon. I want the page to move up and down when we hold down the button. (In short, what I want are buttons that act as a scroll bar.)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. SO is not a forum, tutorial or coding for others side. The SO community "merely" help with specific coding issues such as debugging help. It is expected that you already can code, have done sufficient research and tried to solve an issue on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you are expected to show your best attempt and explain what you run into, after which people can help you solve the bug or problem you're encountering. Keep that in mind next time when asking a question :p

In this case, I'd suggest using `window.scroll()`, [documentation can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll).

```js
function scrollDown() {
  window.scroll(0, window.scrollY + 50);
}
```

Where `scroll` takes an x and y coordinate in pixels to scroll to. The example above just scrolls 50 pixels further down (y direction) when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var btnUp=document.getElementById("up");
btnUp.onclick=function scrollDown() {
window.scroll(0, window.scrollY - 1000);
```

}

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="down">

<script>
    var btnDown=document.getElementById("down");
btnDown.onclick=function scrollDown() {
window.scroll(0, window.scrollY + 1000);
```

}

I did this but what I wanted was to move down slowly (keep the button pressed to the end of the page)

Comment: Please edit your question to add your best attempt instead of creating an anwer :) in your code, just decrease the +1000 to +50 as @fravolt suggested in their code, and it will be slower. Remember to accept fravolt's answer if it answered your question.